# How to decode HTML entities in JavaScript using in a Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html-entities

I am dealing with Ruby on Rails and JavaScript.
The main basic idea is that I create an object in my model's class function and call this function in JavaScript. The **problem** there is that anywhere the **HTML entities are encoded**.

Now in detail:
In my model's function `getData(firstOpt, secondOpt, amount)` I create an object that looks as follows (when I call the function in the ruby console):

```
[#<JobCompact build_compact_id: 324>, #<JobCompact build_compact_id: 325>, #<JobCompact build_compact_id: 325>]
```

Now I put this into an array (because I want to have more entries in that array later) at the first position:

```
data[0] = firstLang
```

(note: I also tried -> data[0] = firstLang.to_json)

In the end I just return the array data.
Now I call the function in JavaScript:

```
var curData = <%= BuildCompact.getData("ruby", "rubinius", 15) %>;
```

And the error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`
because it translated my result of the ruby function to:       var curData = `[[#&lt;JobCompact id: 841, language: &quot;ruby&quot;, version: &quot;1.609481891837258&quot;` etc.

I also tried to decode the result:
`var curData = htmlentities((<%= BuildCompact.getData("ruby", "rubinius", 15) %>).toString());`

And many other variants of that but I cannot figure it out. 
Has anybody had a similar problem?

NOTE: I hope that post is NOT a duplicate because I do not know where to encode (in Ruby oder Javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer to MY question is:

```
var curData = <%=raw BuildCompact.getData("ruby", "rubinius", 500).to_json %>;
```